# How to graph my multiple linear regression model (caret)?

Tags: r, linear-regression, r-caret

I have created an multiple linear regression model and would now like to plot it. But I can't seem to figure it out. Any help would be greatly appreciated! I used baruto to find the feature attributes and then used train() to get the model. When I try to plot model_lm I get the error:

```
There are no tuning parameters with more than 1 value.
```

Here is my code at what I have attempted so far:

```
rt_train <- rttotal2
rt_train$year <- NULL
#rt_train$box_office <- NULL
#impute na and address multicoliniearity 
preproc <- preProcess(rt_train, method = c("knnImpute","center",
                                           "scale"))
rt_proc <- predict(preproc, rt_train)
rt_proc$box_office <- rt_train$box_office
sum(is.na(rt_proc))

titles <- rt_proc$titles
rt_proc$titles <- NULL
#rt_train$interval <- as.factor(rt_train$interval)

dmy <- dummyVars(" ~ .", data = rt_proc,fullRank = T)
rt_transform <- data.frame(predict(dmy, newdata = rt_proc))

index <- createDataPartition(rt_transform$interval, p =.75, list = FALSE)
train_m <- rt_transform[index, ]
rt_test <- rt_transform[-index, ]
str(rt_train)           

y_train <- train_m$box_office
y_test <-rt_test$box_office


train_m$box_office <- NULL
rt_test$box_office <- NULL

#selected feature attributes
boruta.train <- Boruta(interval~., train_m, doTrace =1)

#graph to see most important var to interval
lz<-lapply(1:ncol(boruta.train$ImpHistory),function(i)

boruta.train$ImpHistory[is.finite(boruta.train$ImpHistory[,i]),i])
names(lz) <- colnames(boruta.train$ImpHistory)
plot(boruta.train, xlab = "", xaxt = "n")
Labels <- sort(sapply(lz,median))
axis(side = 1,las=2,labels = names(Labels),
       at = 1:ncol(boruta.train$ImpHistory), cex.axis = 0.7)


#get most important attributes
final.boruta <- TentativeRoughFix(boruta.train)
print(final.boruta)

getSelectedAttributes(final.boruta, withTentative = F)
boruta.rt_df <- attStats(final.boruta)
boruta.rt_df
boruta.rt_df <- setDT(boruta.rt_df, keep.rownames = TRUE)[]

predictors <- boruta.rt_df %>%
  filter(., decision =="Confirmed") %>%
  select(., rn)
predictors <- unlist(predictors)

control <- trainControl(method="repeatedcv", 
                        number=10, 
                        repeats=6)

#look at residuals
#p-value is very small so reject H0 that predictors have no effect so 
#we can use rotten tomatoes to predict box_office ranges
train_m$interval <- NULL
model_lm <- train(train_m[,predictors],
                  y_train, method='lm',
                  trControl = control, tuneLength = 10)
model_lm #.568
# 
plot(model_lm)
plot(model_lm)
z <- varImp(object=model_lm)
z <- setDT(z, keep.rownames =  TRUE)
z$model <- NULL
z$calledFrom <- NULL
row.names(z)
plot(varImp(object=model_lm),main="Linear Model Variable Importance")

predictions<-predict.train(object=model_lm,rt_test[,predictors],type="raw")
table(predictions)

#get coeff
interc <- coef(model_lm$finalModel)
slope <- coef(model_lm$finalModel)
ggplot(data = rt_train, aes(y = box_office)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_abline(slope = slope, intercept = interc, color = 'red')
```

This is what some of my input [looks like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OOM7W.png) Thank you!!

Comment: You should provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The `boruta` feature selection is of no importance here it just clutters the example. No one wants to copy data from an image, please provide a sample of the data with `dput` or better yet use an inbuilt data set to illustrate the problem. Could you say what are you tuning in `lm` or is this just to estimate the accuracy of the model?

Comment: +1 for the need of a more clear and reproducible example. By the way centering and scaling will not "address" multicolinearity. At best it can help in this matter when your model has interactions and centering might help if the predictors values are far from 0.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an example using the inbuilt data set cars:

```
data(cars, package = "datasets")
library(caret)
```

build the model

```
control <- trainControl(method = "repeatedcv", 
                        number = 10, 
                        repeats = 6)

model_lm <- train(dist ~ speed, data = cars, method='lm',
                  trControl = control, tuneLength = 10)
```

I will assume you would like to plot the final model.

You can use the `caret` `predict.train` function to get the predictions from the model and plot them:

```
pred <- predict(model_lm, cars)
pred <- data.frame(pred = pred, speed = cars$speed)
```

additionally you can provide the cars data set to geom point and plot the observations:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data = pred)+
  geom_line(aes(x = speed, y = pred))+
  geom_point(data = cars, aes(x=speed, y = dist))
```

[image]

if you would like to obtain the confidence or prediction interval you can use the `predict.lm` function on `model_lm$finalModel`:

Here is an example for the prediction interval:

```
pred <- predict(model_lm$finalModel, cars, se.fit = TRUE, interval = "prediction")
pred <- data.frame(pred = pred$fit[,1], speed = cars$speed, lwr = pred$fit[,2], upr = pred$fit[,3])

pred_int <- ggplot(data = pred)+
  geom_line(aes(x = speed, y = pred))+
  geom_point(data = cars, aes(x = speed, y = dist)) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = lwr, ymax = upr, x = speed), alpha = 0.2)
```

or the confidence interval:

```
pred <- predict(model_lm$finalModel, cars, se.fit = TRUE, interval = "confidence")
pred <- data.frame(pred = pred$fit[,1], speed = cars$speed, lwr = pred$fit[,2], upr = pred$fit[,3])

pred_conf <- ggplot(data = pred)+
  geom_line(aes(x = speed, y = pred))+
  geom_point(data = cars, aes(x = speed, y = dist)) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = lwr, ymax = upr, x = speed), alpha = 0.2)
```

plotting them side by side:

```
library(cowplot)
plot_grid(pred_int, pred_conf)
```

[image]

to plot the linear dependence on two variables you can use a 3D plot, for more than 3 it will be a problem.

Comment: Potentially nice reply but dist and speed are not in the cars dataset as far as I can see. I don't understand all the fuss with `caret:train` here (although this is probably related to the initial question). With a linear model `train` does not tune anything. The `finalModel` is always simply the initial full model. The only thing to tune is the number of explanatory variables and that is more variable/model selection. The only interest of `train` with a linear model is to obtain fair estimates of the predictive performance via cross validation in `model_lm$resample`. Or am I wrong somewhere ?

Comment: @Gilles the `cars` used here is from datasets included in base R: `cars {datasets}`. I updated the question to meke that clear. There is no need for caret train at all here (at least for plotting) in fact to provide more insights on the plot I had to use `predict.lm`. So you are completely correct. I added the answer since it was a question from a new user who obviously tried to make a good question but his inexperience limited the scope of his efforts.I am not certain even how much it will be of use since the data set in question has multiple features potentially used by the model.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification ! Maybe `data(cars, package = "datasets")` would be even more safe because users are susceptible to have already `caret` loaded and then `cars` from `caret` will be loaded.